# PDO insert with foreign key is failing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Very new to `sql`, `php`, `pdo` and I am trying to perform an insert statement into my projects table for an existing account and it keeps failing. I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Here is the structure

**accounts table**
id = pk

**projects table**
id = pk
account_id = fk
project_name = varchar(100)
pm = varchar(100)
apm = varchar(100)
est_start = date
est_end = date
contact = varchar(100)
project_status = varchar(100)
comments= text

all related fields are utf8_unicode_ci collation
restrictions are set to cascading for innodb `mySQL` db on a XAMPP server.

**php/pdo**

```
<?php

include "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/core/init.php";

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $fk = '';

    $title = $_POST['title'];

    try {
        $query_get_id = $db->prepare("
            SELECT accounts.id
            FROM accounts 
            WHERE accounts.account_name = ?         
        ");

        $query_get_id->bindValue(1, $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_get_id->execute();
        $count = $query_get_id->rowCount();

        if ($count > 0) {
            while ($row = $query_get_id->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {             
                $fk = $row['id'];
            }           
        } 

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    $pn = $_POST['project_name'];
    $ppm = $_POST['project_pm'];
    $papm = $_POST['project_apm'];  
    $pc = $_POST['project_contact'];
    $pes = $_POST['project_est_start'];
    $pee = $_POST['project_est_end'];
    $ps = $_POST['project_status']; 
    $pcom = $_POST['project_comments']; 

    try {
        $query_ip = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO projects (account_id, project_name, pm, apm, est_start, est_end, contact, project_status, comments) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
        $query_ip->bindValue(1, $fk, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
        $query_ip->bindValue(2, $pn, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_ip->bindValue(3, $ppm, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_ip->bindValue(4, $papm, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_ip->bindValue(5, $pes, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_ip->bindValue(6, $pee, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_ip->bindValue(7, $pc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_ip->bindValue(8, $ps, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_ip->bindValue(9, $pcom, PDO::PARAM_STR);         

        $query_ip->execute();

        echo 'Project Created';     

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

} else {
    echo 'project creation failed';
}
?>
```

This isn't spitting any errors back, but I have a feeling I'm not properly setting the fk and so the db insert is failing.

If you need anymore information just ask, I tried to keep it short and sweet even with all the code/info. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

I've now found this error after updating my code

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fsi`.`projects`, CONSTRAINT `projects_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\include\fill_project.php:50 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\include\fill_project.php(50): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\include\fill_project.php on line 50
```

Line 50 is where the statement is executed with this code

```
$query_ip->execute();
```

I am too new to completely understand this error. My guess is that my first suspicion was right, I am not setting my fk properly. Am I right?

Also just an fyi, I echo'd out my variables before my insert, they are all set, none of them are null, if anyone was wondering.

Comment: did u check not null property for the columns ??? if any column property is not null .. and if u tryin to insert null it ll be a problem

Comment: @PrabhakarManthena it says null "no" for all columns, if thats what you mean

Comment: Yes. 1st Print the complete values before inserting. then u can see the exact problem .

Comment: If there is any null value datz the problem.

Comment: @PrabhakarManthena yes there are several columns not listed in this insert statement, so I need to declare them in my insert statement and enter null or 0 into them? Or do you mean if any of my variables are null

Comment: not Exactly if the columns have default values itz no need. if the columns dont have the default values u need to. And also make sure that the account_id FK is presented in the accounts table.

Comment: Nope, you don't. Some comments you are getting here are quite irrelevant.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I didn't think I would have to insert all values, I ran this insert statement with hard coded values for the columns I had listed here on my phpmyadmin control panel and it just set the columns I didnt list for me

Comment: @YourCommonSense do you feel like being charitable with some knowledge this evening? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually turned out to be a case of a non indexed column. You see I was using phpmyadmin and I had not indexed the column 'account id'. What does this mean? This means when I set the relationship to be 'account_id' is fk for the accounts table 'id' field. It actually defaulted it to 'id' on my 'projects' table because that was the only indexed column. So here is a quick visualization for you if you got lost.

If you're very new to 'phpmyadmin' like I was simply click 'structure' on the table you wish to view, then click 'relational view' at the bottom of your table.

You should see something that looks like this

```
Column______Internal relation_______Foreign key constraint (INNODB)
id          <blank dropdown>        <blank drop down>
account_id  <blank dropdown>        no index found!
name        <blank dropdown>        no index found!
```

Now when you want to set your fk to another table you just drop down that middle column named Internal relation and there is a list of pk's from other tables.. *or so i thought*!
The third column is what makes all the diference, if the column has no index it cannot be defined as a fk for another table.

So doing this does ***NOT*** work.

```
Column______Internal relation_______Foreign key constraint (INNODB)
id          <blank dropdown>        <blank drop down>
account_id  <db.accounts.id>        no index found!
name        <blank dropdown>        no index found!
```

You must first go to your structure view of your table click 'index' on the column you want then your screen will look like this

```
Column______Internal relation_______Foreign key constraint (INNODB)
id          <blank dropdown>        <blank drop down>
account_id  <blank dropdown>        <blank drop down>
name        <blank dropdown>        no index found!
```

and you can select your fk, it will then look like this

```
Column______Internal relation_______Foreign key constraint (INNODB)
id          <blank dropdown>        <blank drop down>    
account_id  <db.accounts.id>         <`db`.`accounts`.`id`> ON DELETE <CASCADE> ON UPDATE <CASCADE>
name        <blank dropdown>        no index found!
```

Then your fk is actually set to the correct value. I was unaware of this. So anyways, thats how I solved my problem. I hope this helps someone in the future

Answer (score 3):

> This isn't spitting any errors back

This is your main problem.
And have to be your first and foremost concern.
You have to be sure that if an error occurs - you'll be able to see, read and comprehend it.
While without an error message your job would be rather like gambling than programming.

Once you got it - you can either fix it or get more explanations just by googleing it. Search results on error messages are among most relevant ones.

To be able to see PDO errors, one have to set [PDO errmode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) to exceptions. Exceptions are better than regular errors in many ways: they always contains a stack trace, they can be caught using try..catch or handled using dedicated error handler. And even unhandled, they act as regular PHP errors providing all the important information, following site-wide error reporting settings.

Note that setting this mode as a connection option will let PDO throw exceptions on connection errors too, which is very important.
So, here is an example for creating a PDO connection right way:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    // other options 
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

Connecting this way, you will be always notified of all database errors, occurred during query execution. Note that you have to be able to see PHP errors in general. On a live site you have to peek into error logs, so, settings have to be

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
```

while on a local development server it's ok to make errors on screen:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

and of course you should never ever use error suppression operator (`@`) in front of your PDO statements.

Also, due to many bad examples telling you to wrap every PDO statement into `try..catch` block, I have to make a distinct note:

> **DO NOT use try..catch operator just to echo an error message.** Uncaught exception is already excellent for this purpose, as it will act just the same way as other PHP errors - so, you can define the behavior using site-wide settings - so, **you will have your error message without this useless code.** *While unconditionally echoed error message may reveal some sensitive information to a potential attacker, yet confuse a honest visitor.*
>
> - A [custom exception handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) could be added later, but not required. Especially for new users, it is recommended to use unhandled exceptions, as they are extremely informative, helpful and secure.
> - Use `try..catch` only if you are going to handle the error itself - say, to rollback a transaction.

Comment: thanks for the knowledge, I was hoping you were feeling charitable with it this evening. I'll set my errors correctly and update the question.

Comment: updated, I think the error is probably fairly obvious. I obviously have no idea how to correct it though

Comment: yep, I get a ton of search results for "bugs" which I don't think this is a bug, I think it's my code being incorrect. There is no existing post with this error and a working solution that I could find